# Promise<any> being converted into ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, zone

I'm using Angular5 in my project. I implemented methods in my api service to return promises

```
method(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve,reject) => {
        this.http.get(url).subscribe((response) => {
            resolve(response);
        }, (error) => reject(error));
    });
}
```

In component there's need to ensure that all data have been fetched before  further operations. I tried to do this:

```
const fetch = [];
fetch.push(this.api.method());
fetch.push(this.api.method1());
fetch.push(this.api.method2());

Promise.all(fetch).then(() => alert('data fetched'));
```

It never reached alert. All gets succeded with code 200.

When I paused execution at line with `Promise.all` i saw that my Promise(s) were converted into `ZoneAwarePromise`.

It works well when I just chain them nesting calls in .then(s)

Why Promise got converted? How to get Promise.all working?

Comment: Angular wraps all the promises for change detection.

Comment: Can you maybe create a short "not" working example on stackblitz? This seems it should work. Also, you can use `.toPromise()` on the rx pipe instead of building the promise yourself.

Comment: How does it impact Promise.all? Do I have to implement my own .all() when working with Angular?

Comment: No, you can use `.all` with Angular

Comment: are you sure your method1 and method2 also resolve the observable? without a stackblitz it's hard to debug, and the code you posted so far looks as if it should work

Comment: method1 and method2 just have different urls :)

Answer (score 0):

What about to use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) instead of `Promise.all`? by doing something like:

```
forkJoin(...fetch.map(yourPromis(url)))
```